# Ng serve won't compile Angular CLI 8.3.21

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I'm trying to get my very first angular app compiled, but ng serve spits this error:

```
ERROR in ./src/styles.css (./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/plugins/raw-css-loader.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??embedded!./src/styles.css) Module build failed (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js): Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/assets/css/flaticon/flaticon.css'
    at Object.openSync (fs.js:451:3)
    at Object.readFileSync (fs.js:351:35)
    at Storage.provideSync (/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/WebDental_Angular2_IEB/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/CachedInputFileSystem.js:98:13)
    at CachedInputFileSystem.readFileSync (/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/WebDental_Angular2_IEB/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/CachedInputFileSystem.js:259:32)
    at Observable.rxjs_1.Observable.obs [as _subscribe] (/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/WebDental_Angular2_IEB/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/webpack-input-host.js:35:51)
    at Observable._trySubscribe (/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/WebDental_Angular2_IEB/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/node_modules/rxjs/internal/Observable.js:44:25)
    at Observable.subscribe (/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/WebDental_Angular2_IEB/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/node_modules/rxjs/internal/Observable.js:30:22)
    at SyncDelegateHost._doSyncCall (/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/WebDental_Angular2_IEB/node_modules/@angular-devkit/core/src/virtual-fs/host/sync.js:22:20)
    at SyncDelegateHost.read (/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/WebDental_Angular2_IEB/node_modules/@angular-devkit/core/src/virtual-fs/host/sync.js:49:21)
    at WebpackCompilerHost.readFileBuffer (/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/WebDental_Angular2_IEB/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/compiler_host.js:161:44)
    at VirtualFileSystemDecorator.readFile (/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/WebDental_Angular2_IEB/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/virtual_file_system_decorator.js:42:54)
    at Promise (/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/WebDental_Angular2_IEB/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/models/webpack-configs/styles.js:44:35)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Object.load (/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/WebDental_Angular2_IEB/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/models/webpack-configs/styles.js:43:28)
    at loadImportContent (/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/WebDental_Angular2_IEB/node_modules/postcss-import/index.js:236:34)
    at Promise.all.resolved.map.file (/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/WebDental_Angular2_IEB/node_modules/postcss-import/index.js:210:18)
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at Promise.resolve.then.then.resolved (/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/WebDental_Angular2_IEB/node_modules/postcss-import/index.js:209:18)
    at process.internalTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:77:7) ERROR in The Angular Compiler requires TypeScript >=3.4.0 and <3.6.0 but 3.7.4 was found instead.
```

Npm 6.7.0

Angular CLI: 8.3.21

Node: 11.3.0

OS: darwin x64

Angular: 8.2.14

Package
@angular-devkit/architect
0.803.21

@angular-devkit/build-angular
0.803.21

@angular-devkit/build-optimizer
0.803.21

@angular-devkit/build-webpack 
0.803.21

@angular-devkit/core
8.3.21

@angular-devkit/schematics
8.3.21

@angular/cli
8.3.21

@angular/http
6.1.10

@ngtools/webpack
8.3.21

@schematics/angular
8.3.21

@schematics/update
0.803.21

rxjs
6.5.4

typescript
3.7.4

webpack
4.39.2

Thanks.

Comment: The error is clear: *no such file or directory, open '/assets/css/flaticon/flaticon.css'*. Is the file there?

Comment: You must include the file flaticon.css in the chapter /assets/css/flaticon/

Answer (score 1):

try import the file without the `/` infront

*styles.css*

```
@import url('assets/css/flaticon/flaticon.css');
```

Comment: can you share  with us the `styles.css` file or create a stackblitz demo

Comment: @Victor check this demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-efuxvp

Comment: shared in answer

Comment: @Victor try like this `@import "./assets/css/flaticon/flaticon.css";
    @import "./assets/css/glyphicons-fonts/glyphicon.css";`